# Dataframe-Normalize each row by row's maximum

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Is there any convenient way to normalize each row by row's maximum (divide by row's max)
eg:

```
df=
A  B  C
2  1  1
1  4  1
0  2  1
return:
A     B     C
1    0.5   0.5
0.25  1   0.25
0     1    0.5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `apply` and apply a lambda row-wise:

```
In [199]:
df.apply(lambda x: x/x.max(), axis=1)

Out[199]:
      A    B     C
0  1.00  0.5  0.50
1  0.25  1.0  0.25
2  0.00  1.0  0.50
```

You can also use `div`:

```
In [205]:
df.div(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)

Out[205]:
      A    B     C
0  1.00  0.5  0.50
1  0.25  1.0  0.25
2  0.00  1.0  0.50
```

Comment: There's also `df.div(df.max(axis=1),axis=0)`.

Comment: @DSM interesting that the default is `axis=columns` I'd assumed that the default was index so started forcing the shape with `.t`, thanks for the suggestion